Importing collection instances from the asset browser messes up positions of the objects
I created a collection containing both regular objects and collection instances and marked it as an asset.
When I import the asset into a new file and toggle off the 'instance' option in the pop-up at the bottom left, the regular objects reset to the world origin. Meanwhile, the collection instances stay in the position where they were dragged into the 3D viewport.
This makes sharing such collections as assets challenging because the object positions get messed up when the 'instance' option is disabled.
I tried parenting everything to an empty, but that didn’t solve the issue.
Does anyone know how to keep this together?
The .blend file:



